# how to setup twilio sms api in ionic angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, types, twilio

[@types/twilio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/twilio)

ran the following code and
installed twilio npm package

> npm install twilio

In my provider i have imported by specifying

> import * as twilio from 'twilio'

when i run by ionic serve --verbose
my console show an error that it cannot find module '../../package.json'
eventhough the library file has one, I will attach an image for reference

[image: error image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The main Twilio Node.js module is not intended for use in a front end application so is unlikely to work well for you there. You are most likely getting that error as the Twilio module relies on some core Node modules that are unavailable in a browser environment.

It is not a good idea to try to use Twilio APIs from the client side as you expose your account credentials which would allow a malicious attacker to use your account for their own purposes.

Instead, we recommend you build a server that interacts with the Twilio API and that you make calls to from your own front end. If you are trying to use any of the Twilio client side SDKs, like [Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video), [Twilio Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat) or [Twilio Sync](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync), then you should install their respective modules [twilio-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-video), [twilio-chat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-chat) and [twilio-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-sync). You will still need a server side component that can [generate access tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens) for those services though.

**Edit**

In Node.js I just did a quick test for importing the Twilio module using TypeScript 2.6.2. This worked for me:

```
import { Twilio } from 'twilio';

const client = new Twilio("MY_ACCOUNT_SID", "MY_AUTH_TOKEN");

client.messages.each({ limit: 10 }, function(message) {
  console.log(message.body);
});
```

Comment: Can you answer what the correct way to import twilio is using Typescript? i.e. something like this ? `import * as twilio from 'twilio'` ?

Comment: @CodyBugstein I've added that to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this format for importing?

> import { * as twilio } from 'twilio'

Answer (score 0):

As philnash said, Twilio is not designed to run clientside. I tried to do the same thing you were doing. And you just have to have your Twilio run on a server and have your angular connect to that server to run it. Easiest way. Send a POST to your server via ajax and then have it run what you need.